# Is there an ordinal-indexed increasing sequence of sets such that every set is contained in an element of the sequence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Is there an ordinal-indexed increasing sequence of sets such that every set is contained in an element of the sequence?**

---

More formally, let $\Lambda$ be the proper class of all ordinals and let $\mathrm{Set}$ be the proper class of all sets.

I'm wondering if there's a class-function $A : \Lambda \to \mathrm{Set}$ such that the following hold:

$$ \forall \kappa, \lambda \in \Lambda \mathop. \big( \kappa < \lambda \to A_\kappa \subsetneq A_\lambda \big) \\
\textit{and} \\
\forall x \in \mathrm{Set} \mathop. \exists \lambda \in \Lambda \mathop. \big( x \in A_\lambda \big) $$

---

The first thing I tried to do was consider the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Transitive_closure) of a given set $\mathrm{tc} : \mathrm{Set} \to \mathrm{Set}$ and look at preimages of a given transitive set, i.e. given a transitive set $\tau$, look at $\{ x : \mathrm{tc}(x) = \tau\}$.

However, I'm not sure whether the preimage of $\tau$ in the above sense is actually a set rather than a proper class. At this point, I kind of stopped looking for a "constructive" solution to this problem.

---

The second idea I had was to assume that $\Lambda$ and $\mathrm{Set}$ have the same size, and to assume that I therefore have a class-bijection $\eta : \Lambda \leftrightarrow \mathrm{Set}$. **I'm not sure whether this is allowed when the collections in question are proper classes. In particular, I'm not sure whether these two proper classes are the same size given a standard ZFC setting and I'm not sure whether I'm allowed to just assume the existence of a bijection even if they are the same size.**

In that case, I define $A$ as follows.

$$ x \in A_\lambda \iff \eta^{-1}(x) < \lambda $$

Comment: It seems you're searching for the Von Neumann hierarchy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe

Comment: @Vsotvep, thanks. How "big" of an assumption is it to assume that every set is in $V$? I think having stray garbage that can't be touched by the cumulative hierarchy is consistent with ZFC but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's a consequence of the Axiom of Regularity: the union of all sets in the hierarchy is equal to the class of all well-founded sets, and by Regularity every set is well-founded

Comment: @Vsotvep Three-sentence Answers are fine if that's all it takes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this exists, for example the Von Neumann hierarchy.

We recursively define:

\begin{align*}
V_0&=\varnothing\\
V_{\alpha+1}&=\mathcal P(V_\alpha)\\
V_{\gamma}&=\bigcup_{\alpha<\gamma}V_\alpha\text{,$\quad$ if $\gamma$ is limit}\\
\end{align*}
Then the Axiom of Regularity is equivalent to the statement that every set is in $V_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.

The proof can be found for example in [this question & answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784257/is-foundation-equivalent-to-forall-x-x-in-v-in-zf-foundation)

---

I don't have much experience with non-well-founded set theory, perhaps someone else may be able to shed some light on the question in the absence of regularity.